# Can't validate my self-signed certificate with boost

Tags: c++, ssl, boost, ssl-certificate, boost-asio

I generated by self signed certificate (with my own CA) and now I'm trying to have a boost ASIO client verify the identity of the server. I verified these with openssl and the verification seems to work.

The server and client code is respectively [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/ssl/server.cpp) and [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/ssl/client.cpp).

I only modified the following parts:

```
class server
{
public:
  server(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, unsigned short port)
    : io_service_(io_service),
      acceptor_(io_service,
          boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), port)),
      context_(boost::asio::ssl::context::tlsv12_server)
  {
    context_.set_options(
        boost::asio::ssl::context::default_workarounds
        | boost::asio::ssl::context::no_sslv2
        | boost::asio::ssl::context::single_dh_use);
    context_.set_password_callback(boost::bind(&server::get_password, this));

    // Use the certificate for my website that I had generated        context_.use_certificate_file("/home/paul/ca/intermediate/certs/mywebsite.net.cert.pem", boost::asio::ssl::context::pem);

    // Not sure if I need this, probably not. I do have an intermediate CA though        
    //context_.use_certificate_chain_file("/home/paul/ca/intermediate/certs/ca-chain.cert.pem");

    // Use website private key        context_.use_private_key_file("/home/paul/ca/intermediate/private/mywebsite.net.key.pem", boost::asio::ssl::context::pem);
    context_.use_tmp_dh_file("/home/paul/SSLTest/dh512.pem");

    start_accept();
  }
```

and in the client:

```
bool verify_certificate(bool preverified,
      boost::asio::ssl::verify_context& ctx)
  {
    // The verify callback can be used to check whether the certificate that is
    // being presented is valid for the peer. For example, RFC 2818 describes
    // the steps involved in doing this for HTTPS. Consult the OpenSSL
    // documentation for more details. Note that the callback is called once
    // for each certificate in the certificate chain, starting from the root
    // certificate authority.

    // In this example we will simply print the certificate's subject name.
    char subject_name[256];
    X509* cert = X509_STORE_CTX_get_current_cert(ctx.native_handle());
    X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_subject_name(cert), subject_name, 256);
    std::cout << "Verifying " << subject_name << "\n";
    std::cout << "preverified: " << std::boolalpha << preverified << "\n";

    return preverified; 
  }

...

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  try
  {
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;

    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query("localhost", "3232");
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator iterator = resolver.resolve(query);

    boost::asio::ssl::context ctx(boost::asio::ssl::context::tlsv12_client);


    std::ifstream ca_file("/home/paul/ca/certs/ca.cert.pem", std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);
    std::vector<char> data;
    auto size = ca_file.tellg();
    data.resize(size);
    ca_file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
    ca_file.read(data.data(), size);
    ca_file.close();

    // Have my own CA added to the list of known CAs
    ctx.add_certificate_authority(boost::asio::buffer(data, data.size()));

    // Not sure if I need something here, the CA should be enough to
    // validate the server's certificate prompted (even if signed by the
    // intermediate CA)
    //ctx.load_verify_file("/home/paul/ca/private/ca.key.pem");

    //ctx.load_verify_file("/home/paul/ca/intermediate/private/intermediate.key.pem");

    client c(io_service, ctx, iterator);
```

However this is not working and the client is returning

```
Verifying /C=IT/ST=Italy/L=Milan/O=MyCompanyLtd/OU=MyCompanyLtd Auth/CN=mywebsite.net/emailAddress=info@mywebsite.net
preverified: false
Handshake failed: certificate verify failed
```

I'm aware that there's no verification being performed in the callback but I thought that the callback set in [set_verification_callback](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ssl__context/set_verify_callback.html) would be called after a pre-verification (hence the `preverified` parameter).

Where am I getting wrong?

Comment: By "self assigned", do you rather mean a [self-signed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-signed_certificate) certificate?

Comment: @DanMašek yes, precisely. Sorry.

Comment: @sehe I have a life outside of this website you know?

Answer (score 0):

It's not going to work with just the data you provided. There's not enough information to validiate the certificate. You should generally call these two.

```
ctx.use_certificate_chain_file("path");
ctx.use_private_key_file("path", boost::asio::ssl::context::pem);
```